# Record All Websites Visited

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, dns, domain-server

I have a home network with about 5 computers (all Windows except 1 Ubuntu), and 4 smartphones.  My current set-up is all devices connect directly to the router.  I am wanting to keep a log of all websites visited, by what device (IP is fine), and datetime visited.  OpenDNS does not work in my situation.  Also, my router does not have website logging etc enabled and I would prefer not to flash ddwrt or tomato or something like that.

Is there a wiki or a guide out there that explains how to use my Ubuntu machine to record all of this information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your ubuntu box as router / proxy / transparent proxy. For best results your box need two network interface cards (nic). In such configuration all systems which should be monitored are behind the nic1 of your box and all traffic flows through your box. Your box monitors the traffic and forwards it through nic2 to the router to the internet.

It is a complex szenario which goes beyond the scope this answer and maybe of  this site. You get more detailed information on sites with tutorials to squid transparent proxy configurations. Good search terms are:

`howto squid transparent proxy https`

Some sites I found are [superuser](https://superuser.com/search?q=squid+transparent), [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=squid+transparent), [ubuntuserverguide](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/06/how-to-setup-squid3-as-transparent-proxy-on-ubuntu-server-12-04.html) and [Robert's](http://roberts.bplaced.net/index.php/linux-guides/centos-6-guides/proxy-server/squid-transparent-proxy-http-https).

I don't reviewed those sides, so I can't state how useful the informations/tutorials are.

Comment: I just tested and my LAN NIC Card (if it's still considered that) is shot and will not connect, so this device only has 1 NIC card (the wireless card).  Is it still possible, or should I look into getting a USB wireless card and finding the Ubuntu drivers?